A family drama on sisters
I am desperately looking for a movie which I watched probably 15 years ago and remember pretty vaguely. Appreciate if someone can help me identify it based on the below points that are all I can recollect: 

I believe the movie released sometime in 90s.
I think Susan Sarandon was part of the movie playing one of the elder sisters.
The movie is a family drama on sisters who live in a farmhouse and problems in their relationship arise when one of the sister who stayed in the city visits them.
As the ending credits roll, a car is seen travelling through a trail surrounded by lush green fields.


Maybe marvins room? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin's_Room_%28film%29
Dont know enough about it to post it as answer, but it could fit...

@kl78 Thanks for the effort, the movie I was looking for certainly doesn't star Leo or Di Niro.

Could it be A Thousand Acres from 1997? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Thousand_Acres_%28film%29)
No Sarandon, but it does star Jessica Lange, Michelle Pfeiffer, and Jennifer Jason Leigh as sisters. Their father retires and divides his farm among them. Two of the sisters accept, but the other goes to the city. Tragedy ensues.
It's the first thing that came to my mind when reading your description, even though it's not quite the same. It's based on a book which was itself a loose adaptation of King Lear.

You are correct. Thanks. Can remember now, it's Michelle Pfeiffer and not Susan Sarandon as I thought earlier.

Is it perhaps CRIMES OF THE HEART? I can't figure out how to post a link. It is about 3 sisters, the eldest is taking care of their dad in a big country house. The middle sister moves back from the big city. 
I don't remember the end, but lush country scene would fit right in. 
Susan Sarandon is not one of the sisters, but they do have accents kind of like hers so you might have thought of her. 
Anyway, worth a shot. Of someone can post a link, the would be great. 

This is the link to the wiki page Crimes of the Heart and this is the link to the movie trailer Trailer. In order to figure out how to add a link you can click on the "?" icon or on "help" (depending if you are answering or commenting ;)

@SaraM Thanks for the effort.
